# How to obtain a graph with the SNR average in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to plot a graph with the SNR average in Veins. Is this possible? If so, how could I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about recording a vector of [the SINR values calculated during frame reception](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc#L215)? If you make this an [OMNeT++ Signal](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:signals) you could, at the same time, record both the individual samples and the average.