# Cross layer communication via Veins

Tags: networking, omnet++, veins

I am working on SUMO-0.25.0, OMNeT++ 5.0, Veins-4.4 framework for vehicular simulation. I am interested on cross layer routing protocol for vehicular communication. Can anyone able to suggest me how I can retrieve PHY /MAC layer  information such as SNIR and RSSI value from the application layer. For example, Veins demo application or my own AppLayer model?

A vector record of the SINR values calculated during frame reception using omnet++ signal mechanism as mention on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063470/how-to-obtain-a-graph-with-the-snr-average-in-veins). But i am unable to get SINR or RSSI value into the veins demo application such as TraCIDemo or my own AppLayer model.

It will be great if anyone could give me some idea how i can do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to change the Veins code to include the values you need in the messages that are passed from the PHY/MAC layers up to the application.

Comment: Dear Sir, do you mean that I need to add the values to PhyControlMessage msg? or work with Decider80211p and DeciderResult80211 class to pass values up to the application. Can you explain it more details?

Comment: Having lower layers attach control information to the message when passing it to higher layers is certainly an option. As you are writing a simulation it is certainly also a valid option to "cheat": amend your application layer messages by a field for storing RSSI values. Then, change your lower layer modules to look inside each received message and, if the message is for your application, store the value in the reserved field.